# calling cmake target_link_libraries() with same target and variable name does not append the requests

Tags: linux, cmake

On Linux, I'm using CMake (3.16.5) to link in several non-system shared libraries located in various directories. For this example, the directory layout is simplified:

```
lib1:
libfoo.so

lib2:
libbar.so
```

Compiling and linking an application works correctly if a single call to target_link_libraries() with all the targets, or if find_library() uses a unique variable to hold the results passed to target_link_libraries(). For instance:

```
    #### foo lib
    find_library(FOO_LIB_FOUND foo PATH ./lib1)
    target_link_libraries(hello ${FOO_LIB_FOUND})

    #### bar lib
    find_library(BAR_LIB_FOUND bar PATH ./lib2)
    target_link_libraries(hello ${BAR_LIB_FOUND})
```

However, an unresolved reference to libbar.so occurs when using the same variable in find_library() an ultimately passed to target_link_libraries(). For instance:

```
    #### foo lib
    find_library(**LIB_FOUND** foo PATH ./lib1)
    target_link_libraries(hello ${**LIB_FOUND**})

    #### bar lib
    find_library(**LIB_FOUND** bar PATH ./lib2)
    target_link_libraries(hello ${**LIB_FOUND**})
```

find_library() actually indicates it found bar in lib1. According to CMake, "Repeated calls for the same "target" append items in the order called.". I even tried using a function/subroutine, but same problem.

```
    function(SIMPLE arg1 arg2 arg3)
       find_library(LIB_FOUND ${arg1} PATH ${arg2})
       target_link_libraries(${arg3} ${LIB_FOUND})
    endfunction()

    SIMPLE(foo ./lib1 hello)
    SIMPLE(bar ./lib2 hello)
```

Ultimately, I hope to do this sequence of find_library/target_link_libraries within a FOREACH loop as I'll have many libraries and paths to locate dynamically.

Comment: Result of `find_library` is **cached**. The second call to `find_library` with the same variable name does nothing.

Comment: unset( LIB_FOUND CACHE ) did the trick...